# Find sum of series in c++ by function

Tags: c++, function, loops

**Find a sum of series by function s= 1!/y!+y!/3!+5!/y!......n**
I don't know how to define `fact` function and is this code correct??

```
#include <math.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float fact(float, float);

float sum(float, float);

int main() {
    float n, x, s;
    cout << "enter n and x" << endl;
    cin >> n >> x;

    s = sum(n, x);

    cout << "sum =" << s << endl;
    return 0;
}

float sum(float n, float x)
{
    float x, s = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            s = s + float(fact(i + 1) / fact(x));
        else
            s = s + float(fact(x) / fact(i + 1));

    return s;
}
```

Comment: `float sum (float n,float x) {float x,s=0;` -- Look closely -- you have a parameter named `x` and a local variable named `x`.

Comment: There must be million of tutorials and examples of factorial functions, in all manner of programming languages, all over the Internet. And it shouldn't be too hard to create one with only a math book at hand.

Comment: On another note, if you divide two `float` values with each other, the result will be a `float` value. So there's no need to convert it to a `float` value. (i.e. the `float(...)` is not needed).

Comment: `fact(i+1)` should be `fact(2*i+1)` Attention to detail is really important when writing code.

Comment: Since you don't know how to write `fact` Your first task should be to put aside this code and work on writing a `fact` function. Only when you have finished that and are happy that it is working should you come back to this code and add your newly written `fact` function. The key to writing any code is break a large problem into smaller independent sub-problems. Beginners get told this (I hope) but they often don't put it into practice.

Comment: In your problem statement, you've got a variable 'y'. Unless I'm very confused, you've chosen to call the same variable 'x' in your code. Why would you do that?

Comment: most applications of factorial do not require to calculate the factorial, same is true here. Consider for example `5! / 4!`, the result is just `5` because all other terms cancel out and you do not need to compute `5! = 120` or `4! = 24` to see that.

Comment: Please remove the blank lines after every other line and indent your code properly.

Comment: FYI, factorials grown in size very fast and require Big Numbers to contain the result.  Simplify using Algebra before implementing.

Comment: The `Y!` never changes, so calculate it once and store it somewhere.

Comment: Take a term in your polynomial and expand it, i.e. instead of using `3!`, use `(1 * 2 * 3)`.  See if there are any simplifications or cancellations you can perform.  Also note that the difference between `3!` and `5!` is that `5! == 3! * 4 * 5`.  Meaning you only need to perform 2 extra multiplications between each term.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there are ways of defining the factorial of a floating-point number (using a gamma function), I doubt that is what you want. Similarly, the upper index n shouldn't be a float, either.

Your series as written looks awfully divergent.

As somebody else has said, it is rare to calculate new factorials from scratch: divisors of them tend to cancel, and whole terms of your series are simple multiples of earlier terms.